# Is an oloid a solid of constant width??

Tags: surfaces, convex-geometry

An oloid is defined to be the convex hull of two linked congruent circles in perpendicular planes each of which passes through the center of the other. The Wikipedia page has more info. I came across a couple of places where this is characterised as a solid of constant width. See [here](http://mnp-club.github.io/blog/oloids/) and [here](https://studiored.com/cad/oloid/). I am not sure it is though. Can anyone clarify?? [image: Oloid]

Comment: What is the width of a solid?

Comment: From what I understand it is defined only for convex bodies as the distance between two opposite parallel planes touching its boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) When we roll the body on the plane, then the mid point between
centers of two circles (of radius 1) has a const height from the
plane : Consider sphere $S$ of radius $\frac{3}{4}$ and a loop $c:
[0,l]\rightarrow S$. Then there is $v(t)\in T_{c(t)}S,\ |v(t)=1|$
s.t. $$ \bigg\{ c(t) + mv(t)\bigg| t\in [0,l),\ -a(t)\leq m\leq b(t) \bigg\}$$ is the
oloid. Here oloid contains the sphere $S$.

Let me explain why $c$ is in the sphere, intuitively not rigorously : Consider a smooth loop $\alpha :[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$
containing sets $\{(\cos \ t,\sin\ t,0)| 0<\varepsilon
<t<2\pi-\varepsilon \}$ and
$(1-\varepsilon,0,0)$. Note that this is not in a sphere. When $M =_{let} \{ \alpha (s)+ l(0,0,1) | 0\leq s\leq 2\pi,\ -1\leq l\leq
 1\}$ and we roll $M$, then it will stop. But oloid comes out from rolling a linked two circles.

(2) Further, intersection between the body and the plane is always
exactly a line segment of const length, i.e. $a(t)+b(t)$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How does one prove those two statements? They are not obvious to me.

Comment: It seems that [the first statement is not true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid#Kinetics).

Comment: @TonyK : In the link, consider in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We roll it on the $xy$-plane. Then at each time the center of mass is changed. And what I mean is about how we construct a developable surface.